# CSV file loading into SQL server database table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a CSV file like the one below which I need to load into database via SQL.

CSV File (opened in Edit++):

```
"ProductID","ProductName","ProductLevel"CRLF
"12","Lux","2"CRLF
"13","Santhoor"CRLF
"14","Lime","4"CRLF
```

I am facing an issue in loading the above CSV file. If you observe at line number 3, there is no value for ProductLevel column or blank(""). Because of this it is loaded like blob with bulk insert.

```
ProductID  ProductName  ProductLevel
12         Lux          2
13,        Santhoor     "14","Lime","4"
```

Comment: Can you post your bulk insert query?

Comment: BULK INSERT [##GS_DATA_Fore Research_TDPositionReport_STP_LS_AA3B995656C240A791E24FDA3FA4E36A9]
   FROM '\\applogs.viteos.com\apps_data\STP\Live_02\TempFiles\GenevaRSLData\RequestFileONLYForScheduler\Data\Fore Research_TDPositionReport_STP_LS_AA3B995656C240A791E24FDA3FA4E36A_9.CSV' WITH 
   (FIRSTROW=2,FIELDTERMINATOR = '","',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n',TABLOCK)

Comment: If you want to bulk insert from a file with inconsistent rows then you'll need to use a format file. Take a look at this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx